# Texto al reportar pregunta perdió la traducción al español

Tags: bug, traducciones, transifex

En una pregunta anterior se trataba el tema de los textos que perdieron su traducción, no se si se reporto esto, pero es un caso de lo mismo, al momento de reportar preguntas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y está traducida [y aprobada en Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/131838377?key=a65ad24661f618e2441ca03696094daf)... Todo indica que es el mismo bug. Antes, en el chat, [g3v4 comentó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42584127#42584127) que ya habían identificado el tema... Esperemos a la solución.

Comment: Es un bug conocido, que va a ser resuelto muy pronto (entre 6 y 8... días!)